# Start new activity from notification in existing task

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, taskstackbuilder

My app receives pushes and opens different activities according to the push type.

I use `TaskStackBuilder` for a pending Intent to create a synthetic backstack in conjunction with `android:parentActivityName`in my manifest.

So far, so easy. When the App is not started, all works as expected. **But if the app is in background** (task is running), the pending Intent also starts my desired activity with the defined parent from the manifest, **but resets** the existing task. The problem is that other activities that were started by the user in the meantime are also cleared.   [image]

So what a want to achieve is:

1. if the app is not started, open the desired activity with the synthetic backstack (MainActivity)
2. if the app is running, respect the current task order and just push the desired activity on top of it.

I can't seem to make it work with the `TaskStackBuilder`.

I'd be happy for some insights.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really do this with `TaskStackBuilder`. It isn't designed for that. It always resets the task to begin with.

I would do the following:

- Have the Notification start an `Activity`. Don't use `TaskStackBuilder` and don't create any artificial back-stack. This `Activity` will run in the application's current task if the application is currently active, and it will be put on top of the most recent `Activity` that is open.
- In `onCreate()` of this new `Activity`, check if this `Activity` is the root of the task using `isTaskRoot()`. If this `Activity` is the root of the task, this means that the app was not active prior to launching this `Activity`. In this case, you can create an artificial back-stack using `TaskStackBuilder` and launch the thing again the way you want it (this will reset the task).

Comment: I came up with a different solution, that enables a flag in my singleton activity helper if my root activity was started. When I create my PendingIntent, I check for this flag. If it was set, then I don't use `TaskStackBuilder` but a normal Intent. This works as expected, but I think your solution is more elegant. I now use a PushOpenActivity that either routes to the real target via normal Intent or builds the activity stack. For everyone using this solution, remember setting `android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest to this activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `PendingIntent.getActivities` with `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`, this way I was able to open stack of activities with correct navigation